# GitPitch. How to add slide numbers

Tags: markdown, reveal.js, gitpitch

I want to add slide numbers to my GitPitch presentation.

I have:

1. `PITCHME.md` with content
2. `PITCHME.yaml` with path to css

   ```
   theme-override : {path}/assets/css/PITCHME.css
   ```
3. `PITCHME.css` with some customization

   ```
   .reveal .slides {
      text-align: left;
   }
   ...
   .reveal .slide-number {
       font-size: 24pt;
       color: #ffffff;
   }
   ```

I tried:

I found that there is `.reveal .slide-number` and added it to my css.
It doesn't work out of box.

**Finally my question is**:

How can I use `.reveal .slide-number` in markdown #(H)SLIDE? Or may be there is an easier way to add slide numbers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GitPitch developers [answer](https://github.com/gitpitch/gitpitch/wiki/Slide-Number-Setting):

Just add the following entry to your `PITCHME.yaml` file:

```
slide-number: true
```

It works in my cases.